# Providing opts to piped bash script

Tags: bash, curl, pipe, getopts

I am trying to provide opts to a bash script when piping the script contents to bash for execution.

```
#!/bin/bash

SETUP_PACKAGES=""

while getopts ":u:" opt; do
  case $opt in 
    p)
       if [[ "$OPTARG" =~ "mysql" ]] ; then SETUP_PACKAGES="$SETUP_PACKAGES mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev"; fi
       ;;

    # other parts omitted...
  esac
done
```

Executing the script in a shell like `./script.sh -p mysql` works. The aim is to store the script in a repository so I tried `curl -L example.com/my/script | bash -p mysql`. This however throws `/usr/bin/mysql: /usr/bin/mysql: cannot execute binary file`.

What do I need to do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-s` option for bash in order to set positional parameters for an interactive shell:

```
curl -L example.com/my/script | bash -s -p mysql
```

Comment: from some reason call my script with curl and url does not seem to work. i know that calling scripts and piping it to bash is with "-s" but the getopts does not work with it. can some please assist?

Answer (score 1):

The above example is misleading because you wait for "u" option but set only "p" option.
Any way here is how to call it with curl:

```
bash <(curl -L example.com/my/script) -p mysql
```